# (Android & iOS) Xamarin - How to get tapped/selected text or paragraph from a WebView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

How can I get the selected text range from a WebView? Is there a WebView custom event like selectedSomething etc.?

--

If there is no solution;

Can I get a copied text/paragraph from the Webview? Is there an event (maybe custom) for the copied?

--

I'd be glad for any help.

Comment: For iOS, you can have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285589/get-selected-text-from-a-uiwebview-xcode) about get selected text from a uiwebview.

Comment: I can see some solutions in native codes but what is the code equivalent in c#?

Comment: Usually, if you find a solution in native codes, you can use [custom-renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) or [dependency-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to achieve that in Xamarin.forms. There is a method called [EvaluateJavaScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview.evaluatejavascriptasync?view=xamarin-forms) of WebView and you can have a try.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time, Jack! Can you give a sample code about the process? How a mechanism can return value from a WebView? Should I click a button after the selected text? If I must do that, it isn't an effective way. How can I trigger when a select text? I could not match the puzzle.

Comment: I did some test this afternoon and I found when I select some text in the webView, then if I click the button, the selected text will become unselected because of the click event. Then I searched the [wknavigationdelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate?language=objc), there seems no method will be triggered when a text is selected. So I haven't find a solution so far. I will update you when I find something.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jack! 

I realized your mentioned and decided to get copied words. It's solved in Xamarin forum, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/396727

Comment: Ok, can you please write an answer here too and mark it so that we can help more people with same problem in stackoverflow.

Comment: How about the Android side, how can I do it for Android, do you have an idea? If you have, please add it as an answer or edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection would disappear soon after we select string. The solution came from ColeX in Xamarin Forum. The selection works creating custom renderer and replacing the default webview with WKWebView.

(https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/396734)

CustomWebView

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

MainPage

```
  //xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:App1"
<local:CustomWebView Uri="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/" HeightRequest="300"/>
```

Custom Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App1.iOS
{
    class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Uri)));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Detect the event of Copy event
Place the code in custom renderer or AppDelegate.

```
 NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIPasteboard.ChangedNotification,(noti)=> {
     var s = UIPasteboard.General.String;
     MessagingCenter.Send<object,string>(this, "Hi",s);
  },null);
```

[image: demo]